# How to make react-chrono timeline box smaller

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-chrono

I'm using [react-chrono](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chrono#vertical-mode) for implementing a timeline in my application, however I cannot set the box width no matter how hard I try. My current implementation looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcvJ1.png).

I'd like to make the card smaller as well. Here is my current code:

```
    <div className="flex flex-col m-5">
      <div className="hidden sm:block">
        <CardSection />
        <div className="h-80 bg-slate-200">
          <Chrono mode="VERTICAL" items={items}></Chrono>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire timeline to be narrower, you should be able to set a width on your `<div>` wrapper:

```
<div className="w-40 h-80 bg-slate-200">
```

If you also want to make the cards narrower, it looks like react-chrono provides a `cardWidth` property. This is untested:

```
<Chrono mode="VERTICAL" cardWidth={120} items={items}></Chrono>
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chrono#props for all of the available props.

Answer (score 0):

in react-chrono docs it says:
"Please make sure you wrap the component in a container that has a width and height."

try it like that: (width your own width and height)

```
<div style={{ width: "500px", height: "400px" }}>
 <Chrono items={items} />
</div>
```

Hope it helps